# Can you use a Power to do Suppressive Fire?

Tags: savage-worlds, magic

Can Powers be used for Suppressive Fire? For example, can you cast a Bolt Power to do Suppressive Fire on an area?

Answer (score 13, accepted):

The question in the title is a little different than the question in the body. As a result, I'll answer both.

**Can powers do Suppressive Fire?**

Sure, if the description of that power allows it.

**Can the Bolt Power do Suppressive Fire?**

No, not as written in the core rules. A GM would probably be more than willing to work with a PC who wanted to create a version of Bolt that did that, but the core power does not.

Comment: +1. The suppressive fire manoeuver requires an automatic weapon. The Bolt power doesn't qualify, but it would be possible to create a power (or a variation for Bolt like the existing "additional bolts" and "additional damage" variations) that did.

Comment: Sorry, I meant the question as an example. If you add the part about /Automatic Weapons/ that d7 suggested, they your answer is completely correct ;)

Answer (score 4):

If a player wanted to use bolt for suppressive fire then I would probably do it as a trapping.  As it makes the power a lot more powerful, it would probably be necessary to introduce some kind of down side to it (can't think of one off hand atm).

Comment: The down side could simply be that the full-auto use has no "off switch", so you can't do (cheaper) single-shot attacks.